# Bootstrap Responsive ASP.Net Menu control for Mobile Phone, Tablet and Desktop display

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css, menu

I following the article [at](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Bootstrap-Responsive-ASPNet-Menu-control-for-Mobile-Phone-Tablet-and-Desktop-display.aspx) to build the menu (download source code to build), but in the article create only one menu for two levels (that is customer services menu), but i want create more menu two levels (example menu About: About1, About2).

Then, In database, I insert two rows as picture: [image]

when running, it do not display submenu (about1 , about2) for About menu (picture as) [image].

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Can you please tell your exact requirement? I could not understand what you are trying to achieve here. Please share your `View` code also.

Comment: dear Rahul Sharma!

Comment: Your binding looks correct to me. As per the article, you need to bind the control as required in the `DynamicMenuControlPopulation` method. Please show that method in your code.

Comment: @ Rahul Sharma! I rewrite my Question for clear. I'm step by step with the article, Do not modify any code, but it do'nt show submenu for About menu.

Comment: Please show me your `private void PopulateMenu` method because the binding is happening in that method. It is very important to show the code that you have attempted.

Comment: Thank you Rahul Sharma very much. Dharmendr has helpme (at https://www.aspforums.net/Threads/113386/Bootstrap-Responsive-ASPNet-Menu/Replies/2#Replies)